# The hexagon in Pappus' theorem and its relation to the more usual form

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

I am reading about geometry. Pappus' affine great (compared to a weaker small) theorem is introduced as follows:

If the angles of a hexagon lie alternatingly on two intersecting straight lines and if two close-by sides are parallel to their opposites, then the remaining two sides are parallel to each other.

You can find a drawing on page 5 of this link: http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~fritsch/GraphikenzurVorlesung.pdf

Can you tell me what is meant by the term "hexagon", as there is no definition of Polygons in the lecture notes.

And what is the connection of this version of Pappus' theorem with the version stating, that the intersection points are collinear.

Comment: At least the problem with the polygon is no problem any more, as the usual defiition of a polygon does not require simplicity i.e. the boundaries can cross.